# Is there a way to force Android Studio to run an application with System privileges?

Tags: android

I'm writing an app for a rooted system that has access to System Properties and other classes that Android Studio sees as error.

I have been compiling and installing my app manually through the command line (using 'mm' and 'adb', respectively), but my work could be done so much quicker if I could just use Android Studio's run tool.

The problem is, if I try to run my app from android studio I get many errors, like:

```
Error:(203, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable SystemProperties

Error:(29, 19) error: cannot find symbol class NetworkUtils

Error:(3, 18) error: cannot find symbol class SystemProperties

Error:(68, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable ServiceManager
```

Is there a way to make android studio ignore these errors and just force run the app and ignore what it thinks are errors?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `SystemProperties`,`NetworkUtils` and `ServiceManager` classes are hidden with `@Hide` annotation.

example :

```
package android.os;
/**
 * Gives access to the system properties store.  The system properties
 * store contains a list of string key-value pairs.
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
public class SystemProperties{}
```

**So, if you want to use this classes in your application, you have to use reflection API.**

example

```
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");  
        Method set = c.getMethod("set", String.class, String.class);
```

more about reflection [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html).

Comment: I'm not asking how to access these classes. I already have access to them, when compiling using mm and installing using adb. My question is more asking how to install a privileged app from android studio directly.

Comment: So you mean you need Permissions and which Permissions is what you’d like to check?